# Conectar por medio ssh a windows desde raspbian

Tags: windows, ssh

He instalado server y client openssh en mi pc con windows 11 y me logro conectar desde mi pc con windows a mi raspberry con raspbian sin problemas por ssh pero desde mi raspberry a mi pc con windows no he podido me da el error "Permission denied, please try again".

Comment: Qué servicio SSh tienes montado en windows? El firewall está configurado para permitir ese tráfico entrante?

Comment: Solo he instaldo el openssh y por lo que revise en el firewall, el openssh esta permitido. Tambien realice un netstat -a y me indica que el puerto 22 esta escuchando

Comment: Prueba conectarte desde otra terminal a ese windows. Si te dicen que permission denied, es porque permission denied :P

Comment: Necesitamos poder reproducir el problema para ayudarte correctamente. Claro que no puedes prestarnos tu Raspberry y tu computadora con Windows. Pero al menos cómo estás conectándote, con qué comandos. Recuerda ocultar datos sensibles cuando lo cargues.

Comment: Busca el archivo de configuración del SSHd en tu windows y compara que sus valores sean lo más parecidos a los que tienes en el sshd del raspbian que sí funciona.

Comment: Alfarobravo, me he conectado de otro terminal he igual me dice permiso denegado.

Comment: masterguru, he conparado el sshd_config y estan iguales e igual no me deja conectar desde raspbian a windows.

Comment: Mateo, desde la consola de raspbian escribo "ssh cohp@192.168.1.149 (ip pc con windows)", despues me solicita password y al escribir la password del usuario cohp de windows me enviar el permiso denegado.

Answer (score 0):

Probando por acá y por allá he encontrado la solución. Al parecer era problema de la cuenta de usuario windows. Cree una nueva cuenta administrador y problema resuelto.